# Not able to Generate right SAS token for azure blob

Tags: scala, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to generate SAS token using java library azure-storage 8.0.0 and generating SAS token at container level, then I am using that sas token for running azcopy command. Following is the code used to generate the SAS token.

```
  /**
    * generates the permission policy for storage account
    *
    * @param blobExpiry expiry of sas token
    * @return
    */
  private def getBlobPolicy(blobExpiry: Date, permissionString: String): SharedAccessBlobPolicy = {
    val policy = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
    policy.setSharedAccessStartTime(Date.from(ZonedDateTime.now().toInstant))
    policy.setSharedAccessExpiryTime(blobExpiry)
    policy.setPermissionsFromString(permissionString)

    policy
  }

* @param permissionString permission string ex. radcwl where r = read, a= add, d=delete, c = create w=write l = list
    * @return SASToken for container
    */
  def getContainerSASToken(permissionString: String): String = {
    val container = getAzureblobConfig().getContainerRef(new String(Base64.encodeBase64(getAzureblobConfig()
      .sparkKeyOptionName().getBytes()))).get
    val expiryDate: Date = Date.from(ZonedDateTime.now.toInstant.plusSeconds(86400))

    "\"" + s"?${container.generateSharedAccessSignature(getBlobPolicy(expiryDate, permissionString), null)}" + "\""
  }
```

I suppose that's the way to generate the SAS token but some how it's not able to generate the right one.

**The Error I am getting**:

Signature did not match. String to sign used was racwdl

403 Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature

**Token Generated by the code:**

```
?sig=P5BfjwRj3fxDWoohchvZmr3w3cEnzjewv8KbX8zUmeY%3D&st=2019-12-03T06%3A56%3A51Z&se=2019-12-10T06%3A56%3A51Z&sv=2018-03-28&spr=https&sp=racwdl&sr=c
```

if I am going to generate the SAS token from Azure Storage Explorer and replace it with my code generated SAS it works fine.

Comment: Please edit your question and include 2 things: 1) SAS Token generated by your code (you can obfuscate the sig part) and 2) Error you're getting.

Comment: @GauravMantri I have updated both of the things.

Comment: Are you running the code above locally or in Azure? What's the time zone you're in?

Comment: Which action do you want to do ?

Comment: I want to write into the blob @JimXu

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following,

```
val sasConstraints = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy
    sasConstraints.setSharedAccessExpiryTime(DateTime.now.plusSeconds(5).toDate)
    sasConstraints.setPermissions(util.EnumSet.of(SharedAccessBlobPermissions.WRITE))

    val blob = blobClient.getContainerReference(repo.getContainer).getBlockBlobReference(path)
    blob.getUri.toString + "?" + blob.generateSharedAccessSignature(sasConstraints,
      null, null, null, SharedAccessProtocols.HTTPS_ONLY)
```

[**SAMPLE REPOSITORY**](https://github.com/Craftware/Kornell/blob/3627187051c6f0b49d1c9522e82ef683b933585c/kornell-api/src/main/scala/kornell/server/content/AzureContentManager.scala)